# Maven Versions Plugin Not Ignoring 4 part version numbers e.g 19.2.1.3

Tags: maven, plugins, version

Hi I'm using a maven version plugin rules file to exclude certain versions.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset xmlns="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" comparisonMethod="maven" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule/2.0.0 https://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/xsd/rule-2.0.0.xsd">
    <ignoreVersions>
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*[aA]lpha.*</ignoreVersion>    <!-- Ignore any version containing Alpha or alpha -->
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*\..*\.SP.*</ignoreVersion>         <!-- Ignore any version where the incremental value starts with SP e.g. 1.2.SP3 -->
        <ignoreVersion type="regex">.*\..*\..*\..*</ignoreVersion>         <!-- Ignore any version that has 4 parts, e.g. 12.0.3.1 -->
    </ignoreVersions>
    <rules>
        <rule groupId="org.springframework.boot">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">2.6.*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
        <rule groupId="io.micrometer">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">1.8.*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
        <rule groupId="org.apache.tomcat.embed">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">10.*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
        <rule groupId="au.com.dius.pact.provider">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">4.3.*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
        <rule groupId="au.com.dius.pact.consumer">
            <ignoreVersions>
                <ignoreVersion type="regex">4.3.*</ignoreVersion>
            </ignoreVersions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</ruleset>
```

The 3rd  line is trying to exclude any version that has 4 parts. Sadly this regex is not working.

Have anyone cracked this issue.

Many thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: What exactly is "not working". Is it not excluding the versions? Is it excluding things it shouldn't? Any other attempts that also failed?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Running the mvn command locally, I was getting:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:use-latest-releases (default-cli) on project : Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.8.1:use-latest-releases failed: Invalid segment, 1, for the 1 segment version: '11.5.7.0'

The version number was set as a property value and not hard-coded in the `<dependency>` tag. Putting the version number within the `<depenedency>` tag, the reg ex worked. However, if your project has a transitive dependency version that has four parts, the regex will not work for these. Sadly, MVN `dependency:tree` does not reveal the source of the transitive dependencies.